# Java AD Group Membership

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I am working on a java web project where a manager logs into a system and then completes activities on behalf his subordinates.  Depending on what AD security group the subordinate belongs to an email may be sent for notification purposes.  I am looking for a java 'hasRole' function that will allow me to pass a network id and security group name as parameters and return a boolean to indicate the membership in the group.  The app is currently using UserPrincipal to authenticate and check for group membership but this requires user credentials.  I would need to connect to AD via a service account then check for membership at that point.  Has anyone seen anything like this before?  All I have found online are ones simliar to my current setup that only check for the user with the active session.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the source code of my Tomcat [`ActiveDirectoryRealm`](http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/xref/net/sf/michaelo/tomcat/realm/ActiveDirectoryRealm.html). I does exactly what you are looking for.